# Fetching Single Row in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm having a problem in fetching a single row in a table. My problem is that I cannot display it. Here is what I have so far

```
let feed: RLMObject = FeedsModel.objectsWhere("id = 1").firstObject()!
print(feed.title)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your code seems like an appropriate way to get the first object whose `id` property is `1`. What do you mean by you "cannot display it"? What gets printed in your `print(feed.title)` line?

Comment: print(feed.title) have an error

Comment: This is going to take forever at this pace... what's the error?

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch the single object with primary key like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let feeds = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(FeedsModel.self, key: "1")
```

Comment: This will only work if `id` is a primary key, which is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: I guess there is a good chance id property is the primary key and OP didn't state that id is not the primary key, hence my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access the `title` property of `RLMObject`, which doesn't exist. This property only exists on `FeedsModel`. Instead, you should cast the object as a `FeedsModel`:

```
let feed = FeedsModel.objectsWhere("id = 1").firstObject() as! FeedsModel
print(feed.title)
```

If you'd like to use Realm from Swift with nicer generics, I'd encourage you to consider using [Realm Swift](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) instead of Realm Objective-C.